# A question about colour temperature

Tags: visible-light, temperature, thermal-radiation, wavelength

[image]

This picture from [Wikipedia](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Incandescence) is a table of temperatures vs colour for incandescence, however the problem is that I’ve been told that for a black body, even something with a temperature of say 2000C (E.g. a red dwarf) will glow red, not yellow white. What’s the solution to this discrepancy?

Comment: This picture clearly contradicts the table from
[Wikipedia - Color temperature](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Color_temperature#Categorizing_different_lighting).

Comment: The picture is obviosly wrong: the white point of the sRGB color space is D65, which corresponds to 6500K, not 1300K.

Comment: See https://physics.stackexchange.com/a/492616/195949. It is true that a steel worker knows by experience that an ingot is white at 1300C. But if this hot steel is used as a lamp in the dark, the surrounding illuminated area is reddish.

Comment: Isn't this a duplicate of https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/304299/how-heated-metal-colors-relate-to-black-body-color-at-the-same-temperature

Answer (score 1):

Everyone is miss understands the black body spectrum. A black body will be most parts of the light spectrum. But as can be seen, the peak speeds out, gets lower and has a lower peak wavelength. So as we increase the temperature, we get something that looks whiter and whiter due to all the photons being released and insufficient for us to differentiate the peak. But as we keep going, we tighten the curve, giving us a bluish light. As much as the colour is not exactly right, as stated by Thomas in the comments [Wikipedia -Color temperature](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Color_temperature#Categorizing_different_lighting), this table illustrates that it looks white to our human eyes when we heat these things. This table can be improved, but it could come at the cost of understanding incandescence, the terms used in forging, and other areas that use this. The improvement can be in changing the temp range and decreasing the resolution to try and give a better understanding on the types of white we may see in incandescence.

[image]